# Custom Editor for a node based on type

Tags: nodes

Using Drupal 7, I'm working on a module and want to have it so when the module is installed it will set a new node type called "project" When a user is adding/editing a $note->type="project" I want to bring up a custom editor for my module that is for that node type. I have been looking for tutorials for nodes and editors for nodes but I wasn't able to find any good examples of making a custom node type and making and assigning a custom editor for a node type.

I also don't know what hooks I need to use to target the node editor. As of right now I'm following the steps from the following tutorial. http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-new-drupal-node-type/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [WYSIWYG module](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) allows embedding any supported WYSIWYG editor to a field via a [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)/[`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) invocation. Here's a link to [its documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1087468). You can alter your custom node type form by altering the its body field `#type` & `#format` elements.

Note: To do this it also requires:

1. The WYSIWYG libraries pre-installed to the **sites/all/libraries** directory.
2. A pre-existing WYSIWYG profile created.

As such, you'll need to have add a `wysiwyg` dependency in your module's .info file and some how do the above work in #1/#2 inside your  [`hook_install`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_install/7) invocation.

Comment: I think i may have described the problem in a way that is hard to understand. I don't want to change a single field. I want to override the entire edit page for the node. I want to make a full editor that shows up for this one type. It will look nothing like the normal editor that has each node field listed one after another. I have used the CKeditor in the past to change the widget for a field what i want to do now is have a full custom editor that will replace the node editor all together for the set node and no other node.

Comment: The `hook_form_alter()` & `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` functions will let you add/remove customize form elements as you see fit. You can use `drupal_add_js` & `drupal_add_css` in there to override the default theming if you're looking to present the form in manner different from its default incarnation.

Comment: so everything on that page can be altered by the `hook_form_alter()` & `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` hooks?

Comment: will this work if i want to for example a toolbar on a side that has draggable elements into a center section. This would then update the node.

Comment: You can alter all the form elements that will render in the content area of your theme with `hook_form_alter()`. Other parts of theme surrounding the form will stay the same unless you inject other JS/CSS (via `$form['#attached']['js']` & `$form['#attached']['css']`) to manipulate it. Your own limitation is what you're capable of with JS/CSS.